# Flutter web: remained cached after change web version and nginx cache policy is disabled

Tags: docker, nginx, flutter-web

I build a flutter web app and deployed it via docker nginx hosting on my local.

```
flutter build web --pwa-strategy=none
```

I added version number in **build/web/index.html**

```
  <script src="main.dart.js?version=1" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

Adding meta Data in our header in index.html:

```
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

And in nginx container config :

```
root@496988ac365e:/# nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

I added these configurations in this path :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;

        # kill cache
        sendfile off;
        add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
        add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        if_modified_since off;
        expires off;
        etag off;
    }
```

Now I deployed a newer version of my **pwa** and I change src="main.dart.js?version=3", but I still get the old page shown form the first deploy. What is going on !!! How can I disable caching ? I don't want to do clear cache on browser to see new release of web page.

[image]

I have a sharedPrefarences so that if user do login for first time for example with by password , for other login don't need to insert password, because I store a flag in sharedPrefarences. But after update version I want to be deleted this sharedPrefarences. But Nothing happen and after changing version it remained .

Comment: How are you starting the containers?  In particular, do you have a volume that is replacing the updated content in the image with older content from the volume?

Comment: `docker run -it  -d -p 8081:80 --name web -v /mnt/Project/Flutter/Projects/app_web2/build/web:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx`
@DavidMaze